# Data Type Error when create a new user Knex Postgresql Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, backend, knex.js

I have this createUser method:

```
const createUser = (request, response) => {
   const { username, password, score } = request.body
   
   database("user")
   .select()
   .where({ username })
   .first()
   .then(user => {
       if (!user) {
           return bcrypt.hash(password, 12)
               .then(hashedPassword => {
                   return database("user").insert({
                       username, password_digest: hashedPassword, score
                   }).returning("*")
               })
               .then(users => {
                   const secret = "HERESYOURTOKEN"
                   jwt.sign(users[0], secret, (error, token) => {
                   console.log(users[0])
                   response.json({ token, user: users[0] })
                   })
               })
       }
           response.send("Please choose another username")
   }).catch(error => {
       response.status(401).json({
           error: error.message
       })
   })
   
}
```

And this Authentication method:

```
function authenticate(request, response, next){
    const token  = request.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    const secret = "HERESYOURTOKEN";
    if (!token) {
        response.sendStatus(401)
    }
    let id = null
    try {
        id = jwt.verify(token, secret)
    } catch(error){
        response.sendStatus(403)
    }
    const user = database("user")
        .select()
        .where("id", id)
        .first()

    request.user = user;
    next();
}
```

And when I use the Postman to create a new user it gives me 401 Unauthorized error with message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpXyR.png)

The score data type is integer:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.createTable("user", table => {
      table.increments()
      table.string("username")
      table.string("password_digest")
      table.integer("score")
  })
};

exports.down = function(knex) {
  return knex.schema.dropTableIfExists("user")
};
```

Probably someone can help me with it.

Comment: Add `console.error(error)` in the `.catch(() => {})` so you can see what function is throwing the error. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67574073/edit) your question to add details.

Comment: As I already wrote above it gives TypeError: Unexpected data type (number) and 401 Unauthorized

Answer (score 0):

The error should be from `jwt.sign()` where your secret is not in a right format.

Can you try a simple `const secret = "ABC"` to see if it works?